# How to use Tasks to simplify Delegate.BeginInvoke/Delegate.EndInvoke?

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, delegates, task

Trying to wrap my head around the Tasks class, and more specifically, the `Task.Factory.FromAsync` method.

Currently in my code I am doing something like this:

```
var handler = MyEvent;

if (handler != null)
{
    handler.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is synchronous and I am looking for the asynchronous version. I could use BeginInvoke and EndInvoke but it seems like a bit of a waste considering I don't need a callback. I believe I heard somewhere it is possible to use one of the Task.Factory methods to simplify this call where a dummy callback would then not be necessary. Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's somewhat unusual to invoke event handlers asynchronously; if the handler wants to process the event asynchronously, it should start a Task itself.

You can start a Task with the [Task.Factory.StartNew Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx)*:

```
void MyClass_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // do work
    });
}
```

*(* or the [Task.Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the Async CTP or .NET 4.5)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would `// do work` basically be replaced with the code example I used in my original post?

Comment: My code is the event handler, not the code that raises the event.